# How to sort SftTree control when click on column hedders ..?

Tags: c#, c++, vb6, activex, activexobject

can any one please guide me to sort the sfttree column headers.

I have seen so many web pages as well but am not able to find appropriate logic to sort in c# or else other languages as well.!

here I am not able to upload image ,can you please check this link for sfttree image for example which I took.
http://www.hallogram.com/sfttree/

Ex : If I click on the Printer ,all the items or values with in the Printer should sorted order(ascending or descending) or if I click on the Description those values should sorted order,

I have checked the sfttree.ocx in that there is no events related to sorting,there is only one event called sort_compare event but it is not firing...

please suggest me to proceed to better way.

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties. There may be a property to enable sorting, such as the `sorted` property in a VB6 listview.

Comment: Hi,
  Thanks for your reply,but I didn't find any properties in sfttree which are related to sorting r sorted.